# Trying with C++ graphics, i have included the header files, even getting error?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++. Presently I am following a book called “Object Oriented Programing in C++” fourth edition (by Robert Lafore). In this book on page number 225 there is an example about object and classes. I have share the example below, and have manage to download included files and extracted them in to the project folder. 
So now my project file is contains a file called “msoftcon.c ” and “msoftcon.h”. When I try to compile the project I get an error “undefined reference to  ‘init_graphics()’ ”, whereas this function is very much in msoftcon.c.
Example is  as follow:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "msoftcon.h"
 using namespace std;

 class circle
 {
        protected:

            int xCo, Yco;       //coordinates of center
            int radius;
            color fillcolor;    //color
            fstyle fillstyle;   //fill pattern

        public:

            void set(int x, int y, int r, color fc, fstyle fs)
                    {
                        xCo = x;
                        Yco = y;
                        radius = r;
                        fillcolor = fc;
                        fillstyle = fs;
                    }
            void draw()
                    {
                            set_color(fillcolor);           //set color
                            set_fill_style(fillstyle);      //set till
                            draw_circle(xCo, Yco, radius);  //draw solid circle
                    }

   };

 int main()
{
      init_graphics();

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: Do you *link* with the `msoftcon.c` file? If you rebuild your project files, does it list that source file (or its generated object file) in the build log?

Comment: "undefined reference to ‘init_graphics()" - means you have to add the required *library* that contains the *init_graphics()* function. And, please, always provide the COMPLETE error message!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you failed to add `msoftcon.c` and the associated .h to your project. Merely unpacking it in your project directly is not enough. It needs to be actually added to the project, after which it will be compiled and linked with the other files, hopefully eliminating the error you are seeing.

Exactly how that is done depends on your setup (IDE etc.).

Comment: I did manage to add this file to project in Code Block...thanks for your help!

Comment: @Study2C no problem. So you fixed your issue? If so, mark this as the answer.